# How to use the DeleteFile windows API function when path goes into start menu

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to use the DeleteFile() function in windows, but any time I put start menu in the file path the function fails.  This seems to be the case with several other functions but I was able to find alternate ways to code those.

The msdn page for this function is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx.

The parameter type is LPCSTR which is a C string.  I'm not very good with C strings so that could be why I have a problem with this.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
# if defined(_MSC_VER)
# ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE (1)
# endif
# pragma warning(disable : 4996)
# endif

#include<Windows.h>
#include<string>
#include<lmcons.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

string get_path();
void terminate_process();
void uninstall(string noLock);
void install(string noLock);
void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction);


int main()
{   
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    string noLock = get_path();
    ifstream file(noLock.c_str());
        if (file)
        {
            if (MessageBox(0, "NoLock is already installed.  Do you wish to delete it?", "Proceed?", MB_YESNO) == 6)
            {
                terminate_process();
                uninstall(noLock);
                if (file)
                    MessageBox(0, "NoLock uninstall encountered an error and will close.", "Uninstall failed", MB_OK);
                return 0;
            }
        }
        terminate_process();
        install(noLock);
}

string get_path()
{

    string path;
    char user[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;
    GetUserName(user, &username_len);
    string username(user);
    path = "C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\start menu\\Programs\\Startup";
    string noLock = path + "\\nolock.exe";
    return noLock;
}

void terminate_process()
{

    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, "nolock.exe") == 0)
            {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(snapshot);
    Sleep(1500);
}

void install(string noLock)
{

    if (!CopyFile("nolock.exe", noLock.c_str(), false))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Installation failed.", NULL, MB_OK);
        return;
    }
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", noLock.c_str(), NULL, NULL, 0);
    MessageBox(NULL, "Installation complete.", "Success", MB_OK);

}

void uninstall(string noLock)
{

    if (DeleteFile(noLock.c_str()))
        MessageBox(0, "Uninstall has completed successfully.", "Uninstall complete", MB_OK);

}
```

Comment: DeleteFile handles paths with spaces perfectly well.  Please show your code.

Comment: `DeleteFile` works just fine on paths with spaces. The problem lies elsewhere. Start menu normally contains shortcuts, and those are files with `.lnk` extension (usually invisible in Explorer). Does your path specify such extension?

Comment: I believe the issue is most likely a permissions/security issue.  You should call GetLastError() for details on the reason it failed (see the Returns/Remarks section)

Comment: It doesn't work with program files either.  I ran GetLastError and got GetCurrentDirectory error.

Comment: Where is the path actually coming from? E.g. if you're getting it from `argv` you'll need to put quotes around the string on the command line.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I create the path in the code.  I know the path works because I verify that the file exists first.  I also use the same path variable to run shellExecute in another part of my program

Comment: Well I promise you that the spaces aren't the issue. What actual error code do you get from `GetLastError` ("GetCurrentDirectory" is not an error code).

Comment: Won't work if username contains Unicode characters.  Use wide strings and UTF16.

Comment: @Richard Critten only ASCII characters in the username

Comment: @Jonathan Potter OK I used the exact code for GetLastError that msdn uses as an Example and the pop up box says "GetProcessID faile with error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."  I only run into this problem if I go past start menu in my path.

Comment: Since the executable is in the Startup folder, perhaps it is running?

Comment: @Harry Johnston I terminate the process before attempting to delete it.  Also on all my debug runs it was never running after the first time.  I have deleted the file manually to be certain it wasn't running.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I put my entire code in the original post now.  It is a simple setup file that can be used to install/uninstall a .exe file into the startup folder.

Comment: This "Windows Dev Center" page on "DeleteFile function" gives some other reasons (too many to list here) why DeleteFile might not work as you expect. `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx`

Comment: You can't delete the file because the `ifstream file` object has it open.  Close it before calling uninstall(), or use a different method of testing for the file's existence.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yup that's it.  It worked when I put it in other folders because I never changed my check for it om ifstream.  Put that as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer for you.

Comment: Next time you ask, please go straight to an mcve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete the file because the `ifstream file` object has it open.

(It is possible to delete a file that is open, but only if file was opened with the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag, which `ifstream` doesn't do.  Also the file is only *actually* deleted after the last handle is closed.)

Answer (score 3):

Just about every function you have written has a logic bug in it.  From misusing paths, skipping processes in your enumeration, to lack of adequate error handling in general. Try something more like this instead:

```
# if defined(_MSC_VER)
# ifndef _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
# define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE (1)
# endif
# pragma warning(disable : 4996)
# endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <string>

using std::wstring;

bool get_path(wstring &noLock);
bool terminate_process();
bool uninstall(const wstring &noLock);
bool install(const wstring &noLock);
bool start(wstring noLock);

int main()
{   
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    wstring noLock;
    if (!get_path(noLock)) goto InstallError;
    if (GetFileAttributesW(noLock.c_str()) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Check NoLock existence failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
            goto InstallError;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (MessageBoxW(NULL, L"NoLock is already installed.  Do you wish to delete it?", L"Proceed?", MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        {
            if (!terminate_process()) goto UninstallError;
            if (!uninstall(noLock)) goto UninstallError;

            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Uninstall has completed successfully.", L"Uninstall complete", MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    if (!terminate_process()) goto InstallError;
    if (!install(noLock)) goto InstallError;

    if (start(noLock))
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Installation complete.", L"Success", MB_OK);
    else
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Installation complete, but NoLock could not be started. Will start on next reboot.", L"Warning", MB_OK);

    return 0;

InstallError:
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"NoLock install encountered an error and will close.", L"Install failed", MB_OK);
    return -1;

UninstallError:
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"NoLock uninstall encountered an error and will close.", L"Uninstall failed", MB_OK);
    return -1;
}

bool get_path(wstring &noLock)
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH + 1];
    if (SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_STARTUP, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path) != S_OK)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Get NoLock path failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    noLock = wstring(path) + L"\\nolock.exe";
    return true;
}

bool terminate_process()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32W entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(entry);
    bool found = false;

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Process enumeration failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    if (Process32FirstW(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (wcsicmp(entry.szExeFile, L"nolock.exe") == 0)
            {
                found = true;

                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                if (!hProcess)
                {
                    CloseHandle(snapshot);
                    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Process termination failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
                    return false;
                }

                if (!TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0))
                {
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    CloseHandle(snapshot);
                    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Process termination failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
                    return false;
                }

                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE);
    }

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
    {
        CloseHandle(snapshot);
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Process enumeration failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (found)
        Sleep(1500);

    return true;
}

bool install(const wstring &noLock)
{
    if (!CopyFileW(L"nolock.exe", noLock.c_str(), FALSE))
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Installation failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool uninstall(const wstring &noLock)
{
    if (!DeleteFileW(noLock.c_str()))
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Uninstallation failed.", L"Error", MB_OK);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool start(wstring noLock)
{
    STARTUPINFOW si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    if (!CreateProcessW(NULL, &noLock[0], NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        return false;

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.bProcess);

    return true;
}
```